# Get image resolution ( theBufferedImage )

Tags: java, maven

how do I get the resolution of an image.

```
BufferedImage theBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/tmp/foo.jpg"));
int width = theBufferedImage.getWidth();
int height = theBufferedImage.getHeight();
int resolution = ???
```

Regards,
saromba

Comment: Are you talking about DPI?

Comment: yes. I mean the dpi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get DPI or any other such information out of `BufferedImage`, you'll have to examine the original JPEG file for it. It's just a raster image without any metadata. If you're writing a `BufferedImage` to a file, you can set the DPI. But `BufferedImage` itself has no concept of DPI, it's just pixels.

Comment: Yes, its true. If you have an image file, you can do so. https://dnhome.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/java-read-information-of-image-height-width-resolution/

Comment: @mesutpiskin yes, that's what I said. But `BufferedImage` itself doesn't contain the information.